# VBA: Deleting Filtered Cells (Not the Entire Row)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to filter cells and then delete those left visible. I can usually do this fine with:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A3:I3").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    .Range("A3").Value = "2/12/2015"
    LR = .Range("A:A").Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    .Range("A1:I" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & Evaluate("=TODAY() - 40")
    .UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).Rows.Delete
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter
    .Calculate
End With
```

However, this time I'm doing it on a sheet with a pivot table next to the filtered range, so I get a '1004' error where it can't make the change as it will affect a PivotTable. I don't want to delete parts of the Pivot, just the range I'm trying to filter.

How can I do this?

Comment: Put the PivotTable on a different sheet.

Comment: Unfortunately that would entail a ton of rework. I'm assuming there are other options since I can do things like deleting a referenced range and shifting cells up without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this, if you're not going to move the calculations into VBA entirely... is to clear the cells and then sort. Deleting rows has all kinds of side effects and depending on the workbook settings is extremely costly in terms of computation.

Answer (score 0):

Your data range should be formatted as a table; I tend to call the sheet "Data" and the table on the Data sheet "tData" (similar for all tables in the workbook). Tables have the benefit of not requiring any formatting code as this propagates down as new rows are added to the table and you dont need range("A1:Z" & lastrow) etc!

ok so filter column 10 and delete all rows where cell value = 2

```
Dim tbl as ListObject

Set tbl = Sheets("Data").ListObjects("tData")                'create tbl ref
With tbl
    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="2"              'apply filter
    .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete    'delete results
    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=10                              'remove filter
End With
set tbl = Nothing                                            'kill tbl ref
```

Comment: Suppress display alerts in case 2 is all values in table?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you want to use `Range.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp` on those cells as opposed to the entire row. So just filter the target ranges as you normally would, and use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`to grab the ranges to be removed.

Note that since Excel only lets you remove entire row when in filtered mode, make sure to do `Range.Delete` after you remove the filter.